# How do you organise 1 VS Team Services release definition for separate app and db deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, database-deployment

I have 2 different Visual Studio solutions. 1 for my asp.net web application and 1 for my database (dacpac). I have included the required deployment tasks under 1 release definition in order to publish my web app and database at the same time.

Now, I would like to have more flexibility and do the following;
1) Release web and db at the same time.
2) Release only web.
3) Release only db.

I do not want to create 3 separate release definitions to avoid any duplication and re-use the defined tasks as much as possible.

How could you achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create different release definitions for each combo, there's no way around that. However, you can use task groups to create reusable groups of tasks related to each deployment.